# What does "hoodwinked" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, synonyms

> The former headmistress of the school said she had been "hoodwinked"
>   by Savile, but described some of those who had brought the
>   allegations as "delinquents".

Source: [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Savile_sexual_abuse_scandal) ([permalink to section "Background"](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Jimmy_Savile_sexual_abuse_scandal&oldid=540106296#Background))

Comment: What did your research find on the meaning of the word?

Comment: @GEdgar: something like lying. But I don't get why not say it straight out. There ought to be some connotation of hidden meaning that I don't know yet. This is why I asked.

Comment: It's not like *lying* it's like *tricked*.

Comment: @Jim: is there any connotation intended? Is it "mincing" the word *tricked*? Please, by all means, write up an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be ***"hoodwinked"*** is to be tricked or deceived.

> Some other synonyms:
>
> cheat, bamboozle, delude, beguile

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer. Is there any connotation intended in this context? Does the headmistress try to "mince" her words by using this instead of using what I perceive as stronger synonyms?

Comment: Coming from a different culture than those involved in the referenced article, I think the word "hoodwinked" is indeed mincing words.  This is not a case of someone outwitting someone out of a chocolate bar, this is someone who was misled by a pedophile. Good call and good question, @0xC0000022L!